# Drawing a bar graph with mathematical formula as x axis labels

Tags: symbols, math-operators

I am trying to make a bar graph similar to the one pictured below but am having trouble because I can't find a way to make the x axis labels without errors as they are represented by `$\ket{000}$` etc.

[image]

Below is what I'm trying to make work

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    x tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
    ylabel=Year,
    enlargelimits=0.05,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.1)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ybar interval=0.7,
]
\addplot 
    coordinates {($\ket{000}$,4) ($\ket{001}$,4)
         ($\ket{010}$,7) ($\ket{011}$,-5) ($\ket{100}$,3)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Please provide a starter document, not just a `\ket{000}$` command. I suppose you're using the `braket` package?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
            ylabel=Year,
            enlargelimits=0.05,
            legend style={at={(0.5,-0.1)},anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
            ybar interval=0.7,
            symbolic x coords = {$\ket{000}$, $\ket{001}$, $\ket{010}$, $\ket{011}$, $\ket{100}$, 6}
        ]
        \addplot 
        coordinates {($\ket{000}$,4) ($\ket{001}$,4) ($\ket{010}$,7) ($\ket{011}$,-5) ($\ket{100}$,3) (6,3)};
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to do similar with the X axis?

Comment: @user3730804 Do you intend to put the labels on the Y axis and have the bar chart horizontally?

Comment: Sorry, I managed to find this out, thanks anyway

Comment: @user3730804 Better that way, you're welcome!